# Is there a way, in C, to ensure a function is called only once without pthread_once?

Tags: c, static-variables, variable-initialization

In `C`, is there a way to ensure a function is called only once without using `pthread_once`?

The following works in `C++` but apparently not in `C` because initialization of a static variable must be to a constant (as I interpret the compile error)

```
// main.c

int func()
{
  return 42;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  static int i = func();
  return 0;
}
```

I thought using the comma operator might get around this, but that doesn't work either:

```
// main.c

int func()
{
  return 42;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  static int i = ( func(), 42 );
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation of both results in the following compile error:

```
> gcc -g main.c
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:10:18: error: initializer element is not constant
```

Are there any ways to circumvent this and ensure a function is only invoked once (from a calling function scope) without using `pthread_once`?

To be specific, I don't want to *return early from `func()`* if it has been called once, I'm interested in compile-time assurance that `func()` is only *called* once from a calling function scope - i.e. similar to how `C++` would handle the above code.
(In other words, the above code is legal to a `C++` compiler, which ensures `func()` is only called once - is there an equivalent way to do this in `C` without `pthread_once`?)

**EDIT:**
I didn't phrase this ideally in the original post: I was looking for a solution that didn't involve wrapper/helper functions or variables; i.e. I was curious to know if there was a *construct in the `C` language* that allowed this situation to be handled equivalently to how it is handled in `C++`. jxh's solution fits that best, making use of a `gcc` extension.

Comment: Is your program multi-threaded or single-threaded?

Comment: @user3386109 - single

Comment: @StoneThrow then why not have a boolean that flags when it has been called? It would be a global or a static variable in the function itself.

Comment: And is `i` actually a variable inside of `main`, or is `i` supposed to be in some other function? Note that variables declared in `main` never need the `static` keyword, because they always exist for the entire lifetime of the program. So given the code in the question, the solution is simply to remove the `static` keyword.

Comment: @JustinMeiners - this question is from a perspective of academic curiosity: i.e. is there a feature of the `C` language that allows the equivalent of how `C++` handles this situation. The answer is apparently no, but as answerers have pointed out, the equivalent can be achieved with a wrapper function and a "guard" variable. Kind of my bad for not being more clear I was looking for a language-native solution, but the answerers did answer my question as stated, so they deserve credit.

Comment: If `i` is a static variable in another function, then a "guard" variable is the correct solution.

Comment: In response to the edit. In addition to being non-portable, jxh's `constructor` solution doesn't actually provide a solution to the problem as stated. Specifically, it cannot be used to initialize a `static` variable declared at function scope.

Comment: @user3386109: I believe the OP was attempting to use static variable initialization semantics as a mechanism to force one time call of a sub-function when the outer function is called.

Comment: @jxh - Correct; thank you for expressing that succinctly. I did a bad job of phrasing that.

Comment: @StoneThrow cool, I figured that the fact you knew about pthread_once, didn't match with the question of whether you could set a boolean :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No way to leverage static variable initialization

Your attempt to leverage static variable initialization will not work. C only allows `static` variable to be initialized with constants, so a function call is out.

### One shot call of a function at program start (or library load)

It is not clear why you want the onetime call, but if it's okay to do it at program startup, there is a GCC specific solution.
You can assign the `constructor` attribute to the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__((constructor)) 
void func()
{
  puts(__func__);
}

int main () {}
```

This suggestion does not perform your specific ask:

> I'm interested in compile-time assurance that func() is only called once from a calling function scope ...

Instead, it assures the function is called exactly once when the program starts (or when the library it is a part of is loaded).

### Use a static variable as a guard

If you need to control when the function is called in the exact way initialization of a static variable local to a function is initialized, then you could use a static variable to track whether your one shot function has been called yet with its own static variable. Other answers have already described how to accomplish this, but for completeness:

```
void caller_of_func()
{
    static bool func_already_called;
    if (!func_already_called) {
        func();
        func_already_called = true;
    }
    /*...*/
}
```

### Use a function pointer!

Another way to accomplish your goal would be to call the function through a function pointer. The initial call to the function would do the real work, and then switch the function pointer to point to a function that does nothing.

```
void nothing_func(int *x);
void initial_func(int *x);
void (*func)(int *x) = initial_func;

void initial_func(int *x) {
    *x = 42;
    puts(__func__);
    func = nothing_func;
}

void nothing_func(int *x) {
    puts(__func__);
}

void foo(void) {
    static int x;
    func(&x);
    printf("%s: %d\n", __func__, x);
    ++x;
}

int main(void) {
    foo();
    foo();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. Your first sentence and explanatory paragraph, specifically, is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: I hadn't thought of the function pointer idea. Now that's cool!

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your function in another function which checks a static variable and calls `func` only if it hasn't been called before as -

```
static int func_internal() {
    ...
}

int func() {
    static int guard = 0;
    if (guard)
        return 0;
    guard = 1;
    return func();
}
```

Now, expose only `func` to other modules.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `static` flag.

```c
// main.c

int func()
{
  return 42;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    static int initialized = 0;
    if(!initialized) {
        func();
        initialized = 1;
    }
}
```

The first time through the calling code, the `initialized` flag is unset, so the function will be run. For any subsequent calls, the flag is already set and so the function will not be called.